# Getting NoClassDefFoundError for BodyTagSupport with TomCat running from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've included servlet-api.jar in the classpath for Tomcat and the project but I'm still getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTagSupport
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(ClassLoader.java:892)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:302)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
   ....
```

Comment: try hitting Ctrl+Shift+T in the java perspective and search for BodyTagSupport, that should validate whether eclipse is finding it and in which jar it belongs.

Comment: Eclipse is finding it (ie it shows up in Ctrl+Shift+T). TomCat doesn't when I start it though.

Comment: So find that jar that eclipse is showing it in and ensure that it's in the classpath for Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BodyTagSupport` class is not in `servlet-api.jar` - you need the JSP API JAR. You can find a copy in the [SpringSource repo](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp&version=2.1.0) or on [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/jsp-api).

Comment: I ended up adding it from the Eclipse JavaEE bundle but that is the right jar